# When should I extract blocks of code to private methods

Tags: oop

When I'm writing a method I try to extract code blocks within that method out to private methods.

For example, should I need to transform one of the input parameters, I create a private method that accepts the parameter value and returns the transformed value. I call this private method from the body of the 'main' method - in essence I try to encapsulate whatever the transform operation is within the private method and name the method appropriately.

I'm really looking for answers on whether folks think this general approach is a good idea. I've had mixed feedback from other devs some of whom favor keeping all the code within the one method. I argue that small private methods encapsulate these single tasks, they argue that the class is kept cleaner if the code in kept in the one method.

It would be great to get some answers from the community on which approach you feel reflects better design or is more in line with OOP principles.

Comment: Can you share some code? A visual example always helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally do the same for many reasons:

- It helps reuse.
- It makes the methods have a single responsibility. This in turn makes them easy to communicate their purpose. I think that the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) not only applies to classes but also to methods.
- It makes methods easy to read and understand. My methods generally don't have more than 6 or 7 lines.
- It makes it easy to later refactor them (e.g. in case you need to decouple some behavior into another object, which is very common as a system evolves).

I use, as a general rule of thumb, that having to put comments in your method body to explain what is going on is a smell and means that it can be refactored into smaller pieces.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

In brief it's generally a good idea.

For more info, take a look at Neal Ford's [Composed Method](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-eaed4/index.html) article from DeveloperWorks. In this article Neal illustrates how to refactor to private methods and thus isolate areas of code suitable for reuse.

> The really important benefit of this exercise is the ability to
>   harvest reusable code. When you look at the code in Listing 1, you
>   don't see reusable assets; you just see a pile of code. By pulling the
>   olio method apart, I discover reusable assets. But the advantages go
>   beyond reuse. I've also created the foundation for a simple framework
>   to handle persistence in my application. When it comes time to create
>   another simple boundary class to harvest some entity from a database,
>   I already have code to help me do that. This is the essence of
>   extracting frameworks rather than building them in an ivory tower.

Answer (score 0):

Well in general you should put into methods code that you need at more places (in order to do not repeat yourself).

It could also make sense to put code into other methods if a method would be very long, then it could make sense to split it up into a number of methods.